# Rand a value different than

Tags: c#

I have an enum:

```
public enum PrivilegedAccounts
{
    User = 1,
    Service = 16,
    Admin = 64,
    Other = 1040,
    Executive = 2048
}
```

and I wish to rand a value different than user.
I know there's this rand (not sure it's true):

```
foo = (PrivilegedAccounts) (rand());
```

but how do I make it to rand any value except for "user"?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
public enum PrivilegedAccounts
{
    User = 1,
    Service = 16,
    Admin = 64,
    Other = 1040,
    Executive = 2048
}

 var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PrivilegedAccounts));
 SomeEnum randomValue = (PrivilegedAccounts)values[Random.Range(1, values.Length)]; //Start from 1 instead of 0 to avoid User
```

Comment: I the last line, have started range from 1 instead of 0 to ignore User.

Comment: Love the straightforward approach. +1

Comment: Thank you for your help!But what about a case

Comment: Thank you for your help!
But what about a case where the value is different than 1 (for example, to ignore Admin = 64), or ignoring multiple values?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry didn't get you, what case?

Comment: you may use lambda expression to exclude values as mentioned

Comment: in digEmAll post (sorry not able to edit previous post so please read in continuation to my previous comment :) )

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
Random random = new Random();
int range_min = 1;
int range_max = 3;
int randomNumber;
do
{
    randomNumber = random.Next(range_min, range_max);    
} while (randomNumber == (Int32)PrivilegedAccounts.User);
```

Comment: Thank you, this will work but in this solution there's too inconsistency in the time this func takes to run...:(

Comment: I get used to write reusable code. If you put it in function that takes value that has to be omited, then u can get flexible solution. If you wanna exclude just User (1), then as `min` parameter in `random.Next(int,int)` value use value greater than `user` (like `user+1`).

Answer (score 0):

1- First counting the number of Enum

2- Make random number between the counts

3- create list of Enum

4- return the index of Enum

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 var myEnumMemberCount = Enum.GetNames(typeof(PrivilegedAccounts)).Length; // Step1
 int count = rnd.Next(1, myEnumMemberCount); // creates a number between 1 and PrivilegedAccounts count //Step2 User is ignored
 Array eVals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PrivilegedAccounts)); //Step3
 PrivilegedAccounts foo = (PrivilegedAccounts)eVals.GetValue(count); //Step4
```

Comment: Thank you, but perhaps I'm missing something, I don't see where is User is ignored..

Comment: @O.San start rand from 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method :

```
static PrivilegedAccounts GetRandPrivAccountExcluding(
                                PrivilegedAccounts excludedValue, Random rand)
{
    var privAccounts = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PrivilegedAccounts))
                            .OfType<PrivilegedAccounts>()
                            .Where(x => x != excludedValue)
                            .ToList();
    return privAccounts[rand.Next(privAccounts.Count)];
}
```

Example usage :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    var randPriviledge = GetRandPrivAccountExcluding(PrivilegedAccounts.User, rand);
}
```